# What is an elegant way to keep track of MQTT topics when using wildcards?

Tags: mqtt

I have an application which subscribes to a topic like `data/stream/#` on startup. As the published topics have the form of ...

`data/stream/<uuid> # e.g. "RGAJLkPjNecWfJvQAAAB"`

... I have to continously keep track of later generated topics after startup. At the moment I am using a simple "resubscribe"-method, which subscribes to the MQTT client in a defined interval. As this can lead to missing some data (which is not a problem in this scope), I am looking for a better approach instead.

Comment: It's not clear what you are doing here. Why do you need to subscribe to the individual topics later? The wildcard topic will always give you all the messages.

Comment: Oh snap, yes it already works this way. I used to work with Apache Kafka (pub-sub like pattern) before and there you have to resubscribe when a new topic is generated and you already initialized a client before which covered the topic with a wildcard. But mosquitto/mqtt handles this more dynamically. Thank you!

Comment: Please add an answer below or delete the question entirely. Do not edit the solution into the body of the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MQTT broker (tested for mosquitto in this case) detects new topics automatically and wildcard subscription also covers new generated topics.

A *resubscription method* is **not** required.